# Linear regression function malfunction

Tags: r

```
variables.null.model <- paste('utalter', 'lcsex', 'utcigreg', 'utbmi',    'month', sep = '+')
variables.full.model <- paste('utalter', 'lcsex', 'utcigreg', 'utbmi',   'month', 'ltedyrs','occ_status', 'marital_status', 'social_cat','GC_linc125_07', 'GC_linc250_07', 'GC_linc500_07', 'GC_linc1000_07', 'GC_linc5000_07', 'GC_pop500_08','utalkkon', 'activity', 'utpyrs', 'cvd', 'utmstati', 'utmfibra', 'utantihy', 'utmeddia', 'utmadins','utwhrat','ul_choln', sep='+')
pollutants_3 <- c('GC_PM10_09', 'GC_PM25_09', 'GC_Coarse_09', 'GC_BS25_09', 'GC_NOX_09', '$GC_NO2_09')

null <- paste(variables.null.model, pollutants_3, sep='+')
full <- paste(variables.full.model, pollutants_3, sep='+')

fun.model.summary <- function(x) {
formula    <- as.formula(paste("log_sfrp5 ~", x))
lm <- lm(formula, data = kalonji.na )
coef(summary(lm))
}

lm.summary <- lapply(full, fun.model.summary)
```

I am working on some air pollution data and would like to run a linear regression function and summarize the coefficients. I have the following code above but I am getting this error:

> Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
>       :1:269: unexpected '$'

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: what does `pollutants_3` consists of ? and also I think `lapply(c(null, full), ...)` should work

Comment: Your `full` variable is a character vector of length 1. So, why do you want to use `lapply` on it?

Comment: @Istrel Look again, it’s got length > 1.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn’t be using character vectors here at all. R has better ways of constructing a formula. Using character strings is a detour and incurs complexities that lead to bugs, as shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Your last pollutant is `'$GC_NO2_09'`. Note the stray `$` sign.

But as I said in a comment, I strongly recommend against using character strings here<sup>1</sup>. Construct the formula directly from R objects by transforming the strings into R identifiers via `as.name`.

You can combine a list of names into a sum by the use of `Reduce` and `call`. E.g.:

```
make_addition = function (lhs, rhs)
    call('+', lhs, rhs)

variables_null_model = c('utalter', 'lcsex', 'utcigreg', 'utbmi', 'month')
interaction_terms_full_model = Reduce(make_addition, lapply(variables_null_model, as.name))

fun_model_summary = function (x) {
    formula = call('~', quote(log_sfrp5), call('+', interaction_terms_full_model, as.name(x)))
    lm = lm(formula, data = kalonji_na)
    coef(summary(lm))
}

lm_summary = lapply(pollutants_3, fun_model_summary)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For a bit of background, using strings here subverts the type system and replaces proper, distinct types by untyped strings. This is known as [stringly typing](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) and it’s an anti-pattern because it hides bugs. Your question is an example of such a bug.